# Is there any way to pass S3 link directly to the Media Foundation APIs like MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL?

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, remote-access, ms-media-foundation

MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL works fine with AWS object URL or http/https link.
I want to read video data using its S3 URI using media foundation API like MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL.

I tried passing object URL in MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL and  its working fine.
I am expecting same behavior using S3 URI.